# SQL Server : AFTER INSERT trigger not working properly, even after making sure FIRE_TRIGGERS was set in SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Unsure why this is not working properly. Let me give some context of what I want to happen.

I am inserting a large number of rows into the `OpenCase` table (about 35 K). This data is from the last 3 months. The `Resolved Case` table is already current and up to date.

Some of the open cases have since been resolved, so I want it to check each row from the inserted table and check to see if that `SUB_QUERY_ID` is in the `Resolved Case` table. If it is, I want to update the `RESOLVED_ON` date in the `Open Case` table with the `SUB_QUERY_CLOSED_ON` date in the `Resolved Case` table for this case.

An example below:

From `Resolved Case` table:

```
SUB_QUERY_ID   SUB_QUERY_CLOSED_ON
----------------------------------
US12332-1          1/28/2019
```

From `Open Case` table:

```
SUB_QUERY_ID     RESOLVED_ON
-------------------------------------
US12332-1        (The trigger should get the SUB_QUERY_CLOSED_ON date from 
                  the Resolved Cases Table and update it here)
```

From the example I have seen, this should be working, but the `RESOLVED_ON` dates are all NULL, even when I manually check a few of the `Open Case` `SUB_QUERY_ID`'s and see they are in the `Resolved Case` table.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [FindResolvedCaseDate] 
ON [OpenCases]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
        RETURN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SUB_QUERY_ID VARCHAR(150)

    SELECT @SUB_QUERY_ID = SUB_QUERY_ID 
    FROM INSERTED

    UPDATE OpenCases 
    SET RESOLVED_ON = (SELECT TOP 1 SUB_QUERY_CLOSED_ON 
                       FROM ResolvedCases  
                       WHERE SUB_QUERY_ID = @SUB_QUERY_ID 
                       ORDER BY SUB_QUERY_CLOSED_ON DESC)
END
```

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is not the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once** and the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select from `Inserted`? It's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: It is not safe to rely on @@rowcount in a trigger. Why? In a merge situation, this will be set to the total number of rows affected by the merge statement (inserted, updated, deleted). This slow loading [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20100102170713/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/steve_kass/archive/2009/04/29/It_2700_s-2008-and-rowcount-ain_2700_t-what-it-used-to-be.-Don_2700_t-use-it-in-triggers_2100_.aspx) to web archive explains.